# Intentionally slow-loading Python app on AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine

I have discovered, as have many before me, that AppEngine has a 60 second execution deadline.

```
Process terminated because the request deadline was exceeded.
```

My use case is a bit different to the others I've seen. I have a web form that lets you move a toggle switch; there's a page you can GET which represents this toggle state with a 1 or 0. A Raspberry Pi hits this page every 10 seconds and makes a light at my front gate match the state of the toggle. I'm doing all of this over HTTP (the Pi is on a 4G modem which firewalls traffic on other ports).

I had the idea earlier today of making a "has the state changed" handler. The Pi would get and match the state at first boot, but after that it would hit a (often very slow to load) handler that did something like this:

```
iterations = 0
current_state = get_state()
while iterations < 600
    if get_state != current_state:
        return "Change!"
    iterations = iterations + 1
    time.sleep(1)
return "No change"
```

This would reduce my 4G overhead to a single request every ten minutes, but - if the state changed - the page would finish loading immediately and I could act on it straight away. If nothing changed, I would just call the process again - but now I'd be doing it once every 10 min instead of once every 10 sec.

Even with a 50s upper limit, I can build this and it will save me some overhead + improve my response latency. But is there something I'm missing about how deadlines work which would let me do this in GAE for longer periods of time?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to reach 60 minutes timeout by switching to the flexible environment. From [Comparing high-level features](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments#comparing_high-level_features):

[image]